# How to request Contacts and Calendar Permissions on XamarinMac?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to access the `ContactStore` of `MacOS` App, did the following implementation

```
public void Contacts()
{
    //Starting
    var store = new CNContactStore();

    store.RequestAccess(CNEntityType.Contacts, async (bool granted, NSError error) =>
        {
            if (granted)
            {
                //Query things
            }
        });
}
```

The thing is that the `Authorize screen` never popup, and the `Permission` always say denied.

If I go to settings to remove that record, the app is not there.

Can someone please point me to the light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me with those two lines:

```
            var contactStore = new CNContactStore();
            var status = CNContactStore.GetAuthorizationStatus(CNEntityType.Contacts);
```

It could be also that you need to set `NSContactsUsageDescription` in `info.plist`.

Comment: Was missing the NSContactsUsageDescription on the info.plist, strange that is not that clear in the documentation found over the internet regarding CNContactStore, this solved the issue Thanks  Ivan!